# Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot call method 'push' of null

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I have an issue I just cannot seem to understand. If anyone could offer some advise I would appreciate it.

I am using Ionic2 with Meteor/Mongo to build a Chat App.

I have the following code:

```
  private findChats(): Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> {
    let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = new Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>>(resolve => {
      let registeredIds: String[] = [this.senderId];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.jobModelsForSender.length; i++) {
        console.log('findChats:  registeredIds.push this.jobModelsForSender[i].id: ' + registeredIds + '  -  ' + this.jobModelsForSender[i].id);
        registeredIds.push('J' + this.jobModelsForSender[i].id);
        console.log('findChats:  pushed: ' + registeredIds);
      }
      this.subscribe('chats', this.senderId, registeredIds, () => {
        console.log('findChats:  in subscribe: ' + this.senderId+'  '+registeredIds);

        let chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat> = Chats.find(
          { memberIds: { $in: registeredIds } },
          {
            sort: { lastMessageCreatedAt: -1 },
            transform: this.transformChat.bind(this),
            fields: { memberIds: 1, lastMessageCreatedAt: 1 }
          }
        );
        console.log('findChats:  chats: ' + chats);
        this.chats = chats;
        let localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
        chats.forEach((chat: Chat) => {
          localChatCollection.insert(chat);
        });
        console.log('findChats:  resolve(localChatCollection): ' + localChatCollection);
        resolve(localChatCollection);
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

But I get the following output:

```
findChats:  registeredIds.push this.jobModelsForSender[i].id: P8  -  72 app.bundle.js:118232
findChats:  pushed: P8,J72 app.bundle.js:118234
findChats:  registeredIds.push this.jobModelsForSender[i].id: P8  -  72 app.bundle.js:118232
findChats:  pushed: P8,J72 app.bundle.js:118234
findChats:  registeredIds.push this.jobModelsForSender[i].id: P8  -  72 app.bundle.js:118232
findChats:  pushed: P8,J72 app.bundle.js:118234
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot call method 'push' of null ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot call method 'push' of null"} zone.js:461
Error {rejection: TypeError, promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask, stack: (...)…}
 zone.js:463
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot call method 'push' of null ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot call method 'push' of null"} zone.js:461
Error {rejection: TypeError, promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask, stack: (...)…}
 zone.js:463
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot call method 'push' of null ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot call method 'push' of null"} zone.js:461
Error {rejection: TypeError, promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask, stack: (...)…}
 zone.js:463
findChats:  in subscribe: P8  P8,J72 app.bundle.js:118243
findChats:  chats: [object Object] app.bundle.js:118249
findChats:  resolve(localChatCollection): [object Object]
```

As you can see, I am getting an error in `zone.js`. As far as I can see, when I debug this, and as the logs show, it does the `push` successfully to `registeredIds`. It then exits the function, returning the `promise`. After that it goes into `zone.js` where the error is logged.

Comment: The problem here seems to be, that the promise is not resolved synchronously but rather asynchronously. Meaning, that at runtime in the code registeredIds does not exist yet. You would need to wait for the promise to be resolved and proceed with your code execution afterwards. Try not only outputting to console but actually debugging it with an internal browser debugger to see when it is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the direction to look in Anton, I will check it out.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I had an event that was calling the same promise at the same time. As soon as I remove the trigger to that event, I don't get any errors. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will probably not be relevant to many people, but as Anton pointed out, that it is an issue to do with the promise loading asynchronously.

I had an event that was calling the same promise at the same time. As soon as I remove the trigger to that event, I don't get any errors.